# How to troubleshoot sublime text 3 goto definition

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 to edit my ruby code.  Goto Definition works for methods and classes just fine, but when I try to go to my constant definitions, it isn't working.  I've looked in the console using `sublime.log_commands(True)` and it only shows the command, but no output or error.

Everything I've found on the web indicates that Goto Definition should take me to constant definitions, so I can't figure out why it isn't.

Is there somewhere Sublime Text is throwing any sort of error message for why it can't find constant definitions?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better asked of the Sublime support? They wrote it.

Comment: can you post a snippet from your ruby code?

Comment: @ABMagil I have a similar issue with my rails project in sublime 3 in 2019 :) I'm just wondering if you were able to solve this problem and how? If you still remember that.